# What's the difference between `HTMLElement` and `Element`?

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between `HTMLElement` and `Element` ?

`document.createElement("div") instanceof Element` gives true

`document.createElement("div") instanceof HTMLElement` gives true

`HTMLElement === Element` gives false

Comment: Well `===` checks that value and type are equal... in your last line, types are not equal, even though one type extends the other... And `instanceof` checks that the object is of the type specified, and if first type inherits the other, then it will be `true` in both cases.

Answer (score 56):

An `HTMLElement` **is an** `Element`, as defined in the [HTML extension to the DOM Level 2 Core specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-58190037):

```
interface HTMLElement : Element {
           attribute DOMString       id;
           attribute DOMString       title;
           attribute DOMString       lang;
           attribute DOMString       dir;
           attribute DOMString       className;
};
```

`Element` (per specification) refers to the `Element` interface as it is defined in the [DOM Core Level 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-745549614) (there is also another [*DOM Core* specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-element) (working draft) though).

**Update:** There are a lot of specifications out there and it is not totally clear which browsers use which one (to me).

Maybe someone else has more insight...

But in any case, `Element` is a more generic interface than `HTMLElement` and the latter inherits from the former.

**Update 2:** A nice way to see the inheritance structure is to execute `console.dir(elementReference)` for any element (works in Chrome/Safari, needs Firebug for Firefox).

Comment: Nowadays, when using console.dir(element) or console.log(element), consoles display an interactive view of the elements, hiding the type and hierarchy of the object.

You can use Object.getPrototypeOf(element), which displays eg. "HTMLDivElement {...}".

Calling it one more time displays "HTMLElement {...}".

And yet another time displays "Element {...}": here we go, we can witness the inheritance hierarchy :-)

Answer (score 54):

`HTMLElement` refers explicitly to an HTML element whereas `Element` may refer to an XML element. However, `HTMLElement` is technically a subset of `Element`.

Comment: Can you think of a case where one would encounter a useful `Element` that's not an `HTMLElement` in web page JavaScript?

Comment: @Bob Stein: Yes - document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0] and potentially document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0] - svg is a svg-element - it doesn't necessarely have element.innerHTML for example.

Comment: This is the more useful answer, as it clearly explains why the two interfaces are distinct

Answer (score 19):

`HTMLElement`s inherit from `Element` which inherit from `Node`.

This means that your `HTMLElement` is simultaneously an `instanceof` all three. The fact that it is an `HTMLElement` means it has an interface that's contains methods only an `HTMLElement` would need like `attachEvent`.

Comment: Actually, `Element` inherits from `Node`.

Comment: @Felix King You're right. I was kind of sloppy and skipped to Object. I've edited my answer from Object to Node.