# Failed to execute query selector on document, id is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a way to edit a bunch of comments and identify them by some id that I can generate. The errors I'm having is that there is:

SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#1234' is not a valid selector. However, I don't see how this is possible since I clearly have `id=1234` in the `<p>`.

Additionally, there are issues where when I comment everything else and do an alert(id), this does not work for the second form and the error is that:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null.

Here is it in jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wafqgq0L/2/

```js
document.querySelector('.editable').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
 var index = event.target.id.indexOf('_');

 var id = event.target.id.substring(0,index);
 
 //actual data
 document.querySelector('#'+id).classList.add('hidden');
  
  //edit button
  document.querySelector("#"+id+"_edit").classList.add('hidden');
  
  //textarea
 document.querySelector("#"+id+"_editable").classList.remove('hidden');
  
  //save button
 document.querySelector("#"+id+"_save").classList.remove('hidden');

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
//all id will be like 12345_comment

<div class="editable">
<p id="1234">
  Some comment
</p>

<form action="form.php" method="post">
  <textarea id="1234_editable" class="hidden">Some comment</textarea>
  <a href="#" id="1234_edit">Edit</a>
  <a href="#" id="1234_save" class="hidden">Save</a>
</form>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="editable">
<p id="123">
  Some comment
</p>

<form class="editable" action="form.php" method="post">
  <textarea id="123_editable" class="hidden">Some comment</textarea>
  <a href="#" id="123_edit">Edit</a>
  <a href="#" id="123_save" class="hidden">Save</a>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: If using HTML4 `id`s must start with a letter (https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) with HTML5 you can use numbers.  Either change your `id`s to start with a letter or use HTML5

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use JQuery? it makes DOM manipulations like this much easier (and with more succinct syntax)

Comment: Don't understand why you're not using getElementById

Comment: @SteveHarris I know this is an old question, but maybe other viewers could find interesting that  `getElementById` returns the type `Element`, while  `querySelector` returns the type `HTMLElement`. Sometimes only one of them is applicable in certain contexts. Please find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6581680/2457251), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find jQuery easier, and it's automatically cross-browser (and faster to type!) Since it's tagged on your question, here is the jQuery solution:

#### Edit: The tag `jQuery` was removed from the original question on May 25 '19 at 21:10 (3 years after question was asked and answered), by user `John`, with the inexplicable editor comment "remove spam tags".

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/wafqgq0L/12/)</kbd>

```
$('[id^=edit_]').click(function(){
    var id = this.id.split('_')[1];
    $('#'+id).addClass('hidden');
    $('#edit_'+id).addClass('hidden');

    $('#save_'+id).removeClass('hidden');  
    $('#editable_'+id).removeClass('hidden');  
});

$('[id^=save_]').click(function(){
    var id = this.id.split('_')[1];
    $('#'+id).removeClass('hidden');
    $('#edit_'+id).removeClass('hidden');

    $('#save_'+id).addClass('hidden');  
    $('#editable_'+id).addClass('hidden');  
});
```

---

Note that I switched around the id_number and the idName_ prefix. This makes it much easier to target those elements using the `starts with` selector: `id^=`

Comment: This is great. Thanks. Do you know if I can make a post request after Save is clicked?

Comment: What you are looking for is called AJAX - and don't be intimidated, it's much easier than it sounds. See [this post](http://stackoverflow/a/17974843) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow/a/34735490) for a quick introduction, and as always on StackOverflow, please upvote any posts that you find helpful.

Comment: That does provide a workaround, but doesn't explain why `document.querySelector('#000')` does throw an error while `document.querySelector('[id="000"]')` retrieves the element just as `document.getElementById('000')` does...

Answer (score 42):

If using HTML4 `id`s must start with a letter (https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)

If using HTML5 you can use numbers.

Either change your `id`s to start with a letter (as in `id="p12345"`) or use HTML5
(i.e. use `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your document)

Comment: I changed it, but still have this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null: https://jsfiddle.net/wafqgq0L/4/  That did not save changes, sec.

Comment: Your code does not do anything when clicking on the `save` button - can you post that part of the code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wafqgq0L/10/  Updates. The upper form works now, but the bottom does not. The save button should not do anything right now. I just want the textarea to appear. Also nothing in the console

Comment: You get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null" when you click outside of the link (i.e. on the div) since the 'target' does not have an id... I will try to add a fuller solution

Comment: However, this error does not appear in the console when you click the second Edit link. I'm not sure why that occurs, but it's like the eventhandler does not see it.

Comment: Actually, `document.querySelector('#000")` does throw an error whatever the DocType of the document. Interesting question...

Answer (score 15):

You can use template string literals for this because id must be in quotes otherwise it won't work and be sure to use HTML5   at the top of your document. With this I didn't have any more issues.

For example:

```
document.querySelector(`[data-id="${id}" ]`);
```

Or if for any reason you don't want to use template literals add this line of code:

```
document.querySelector("[data-id=" + "\'" + id + "\'" + "]");
```

With escape character `\'` in double quotes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector("class or id")` is not using tags as arguments instead it uses class or Id.