# TypeScript set element typing using 'as' to getElementsByClassName

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, getelementsbyclassname, setfocus

Very new to TypeScript so I'm sure there is more than one thing wrong with my code.

```
let htmlOption: HTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName(OPTION_SELECTOR);
let selected: HTMLElement = htmlOption[index];
// this throws an error "Initializer type Element is not assignable to variable type HTMLElement
selected.focus();
```

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the fact that children of `HTMLCollection` are `Element`, not `HTMLElement`. But I needed to set focus on the `HTMLElement` (which isn't allowed on `Element`)

But the following does not throw any errors:

```
let htmlOption = (document.getElementsByClassName(OPTION_SELECTOR) as HTMLCollection);
let selected = (htmlOption[index] as HTMLElement);
selected.focus();
```

I don't understand how these are different. I thought I could declare variables with the varName: type = definition?

Comment: Using `varName: type` says that you intend to put a value of type `type` into `varName`. If you don't, the compiler should complain. Using `expression as type` is saying that the result of `expression` is `type`.

Comment: Similar question, which should answer yours: [whats-the-difference-between-htmlelement-and-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581680/whats-the-difference-between-htmlelement-and-element)

Comment: @Steveland83, while somewhat related, it sounds like the OP is aware of the difference between an `HTMLElement` and an `Element` (from question: *But I needed to set focus on the `HTMLElement` (which isn't allowed on `Element`)*). This question was around the typing information TypeScript adds to the picture.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - thanks for the quick response. Is this an example of what you describe?

**value of type**
`let htmlOption: string = 'Select an Option'`
**expression as type**
`let htmlOption = (document.getElementsByClassName(OPTION_SELECTOR) as HTMLCollection) `
?

and thanks @Steveland83 but I do already understand what you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. the first statement in your comment ensures `htmlOption` always contains a `string`. The latter will make `htmlOption` contain an `HTMLCollection`. You can replace it with `let htmlOption: HTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName(OPTION_SELECTOR) as HTMLCollection;` or even `let htmlOption = <HTMLCollection>document.getElementsByClassName(OPTION_SELECTOR);`. In all three cases, you're letting the compiler know that the result of `getElementsByClassName` is an `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, thank you. I didn't understand that the '... as HTMLCollection' was typing what the result of the expression `getElementsByClassName` is. I think I got it now. Thanks again!